Sections of $F(D(s))$ on a qcqs scheme extend to $(F \otimes L^{\otimes n})(X)$.
Vakil's Foundations of Algebraic Geometry, exercise 15.4.N.
Let $F$ be a quasicoherent sheaf on a qcqs scheme $X$, and $L$ is an invertible sheaf with global section $s$. Then, show that $(\oplus_{n \geq 0} \Gamma(X, F \otimes L^{\otimes n}))_{s : 0} \rightarrow \Gamma(D(s), F)$ is an isomorphism.
I don't understand what the left side means. $s$ is an element of $\Gamma(X, L)$ so I don't know how you can divide by it. Here's what I think is going on : $O_X|_{D(s)} \rightarrow L|_{D(s)}$ given by multiplication by $s$ is an isomorphism (call it $j$), so $j^{-1}$ can be thought of as dividing by $s$. Thus, I think the exercise is saying that for any $a \in \Gamma(D(s), F)$, there is some $n \geq 0$ and $b \in \Gamma(X, F \otimes L^{\otimes n})$ such that $(id_F \otimes (j^{-1})^{\otimes n}) (b|_{D(s)}) = a$.
If $X = Spec(R)$ is affine where $L$ trivializes by an isomorphism $i : L \rightarrow R$, and $F$ corresponds to the module $M$, then let $t = i(s)$. On $D(s) = D(t)$, $i(s) = t$ and $j(1) = s$, so $i \circ j$ is multiplication by $t$, and $j^{-1} \circ i^{-1}$ is division by $t$.
Then, $a \in F(D(s))$ is $m / t^n$ for some $n$, and $m \otimes i^{-1}(1)^{\otimes n}$ is the $b$ that we are looking for, since $(j^{-1})^{\otimes n}(i^{-1}(1)^{\otimes n}) = 1/t^n$.
But then how do we prove the general case? We can cover $X$ by affine open sets $U_i$, and choose a $(n_i, b_i)$ for each $i$. By compactness, we can assume that all $n_i = n$ are the same. But then how do we show that the $b_i$ glue? I think that we need to somehow use uniqueness of $b_i$, but the $b_i$ are clearly not unique. If $(n_i, b_i)$ satisfies the condition, then so does $(n_i = 1, b_i \otimes s)$. I think we also have to use quasiseparatedness somehow. How do I glue the $b_i$ into a section of $\Gamma(X, F \otimes L^{\otimes n})$?
Edit (in response to KReiser's comment) : The full statement of the exercise is:

Suppose $X$ is a quasi-compact quasiseparated scheme, $L$ is an invertible sheaf on $X$ with section $s$, and $F$ is a quasicoherent sheaf on $X$. Generalizing Definition 6.2.8, let $X_s$ be the open subset of $X$ where $s$ doesn’t vanish. We interpret $s$ as a degree 1 element of the
graded ring $R_\bullet(L) := \oplus_{n \geq 0}(X, L^{\otimes n})$. Note that $\oplus_{n \geq 0}(X, F \otimes L^{\otimes n})$ is a graded $R_\bullet(L)$-module.


(a) Describe a natural map $\oplus_{n \geq 0}(X, F \otimes L^{\otimes n})_{s : 0} \rightarrow \Gamma(X_s, F).$


(Possible hint: for quasicoherent sheaves, “tensor product has no need to be sheafified when restricted to affine subschemes”, Exercise 6.2.F.)


(b) Show that this map is an isomorphism. (Hint: show this map is an isomorphism in the affine case.)

The exercise says that $\oplus_{n \geq 0} \Gamma(X, L^{\otimes n})$ is a graded ring, $s$ is a degree 1 element,  and $\oplus_{n \geq 0} \Gamma(X, F \otimes L^{\otimes n})$ is a graded module over that ring.
This implies there is a bilinear map $\Gamma(X, L^{\otimes m}) \times \Gamma(X, L^{\otimes n}) \rightarrow \Gamma(X, L^{\otimes m+n})$. I guess it's $x_1 \otimes ... \otimes x_m, y_1 \otimes ... \otimes y_n \rightarrow x_1 \otimes ... \otimes x_m \otimes y_1 \otimes ... \otimes y_n$. But I don't know if this even makes sense. In general, $\Gamma(X, F \otimes G) \neq \Gamma(X, F) \otimes \Gamma(X, G)$, so I don't know if the equation I wrote above is even well-defined and meaningful.
I tried following the given hint, and managed to prove the statement under the assumption that $X$ is affine. I don't know how to define multiplication in $\oplus_{n \geq 0} \Gamma(X, L^{\otimes n})$ in the general case, nor how to define scalar multiplication from that ring to $\oplus_{n \geq 0}(X, F \otimes L^{\otimes n})$.
Also, I think that the ring is not commutative, as $x \otimes y$ and $y \otimes x$ are usually two different elements in a tensor product.
Edit 2
I think I figured out how multiplication is defined in the ring. I'm still stuck on proving the isomorphism though.
If $F$ and $G$ are sheaves of $O_X$-modules, then $(F \otimes^{pre} G)(X) = F(X) \otimes_{O_X(X)} G(X)$, so the sheafification map gives a $O_X(X)$-module homomorphism $F(X) \otimes_{O_X(X)} G(X) \rightarrow (F \otimes G)(X)$.
Thus, if $F = L^{\otimes m} , G = L^{\otimes n}$, then the map above gives a map $\Gamma(X, L^{\otimes m}) \otimes_{O_X(X)} \Gamma(X, L^{\otimes n}) \rightarrow \Gamma(X, L^{\otimes m+n})$ . This gives the graded ring structure on $\oplus_{n \geq 0} \Gamma(X, L^{\otimes n})$.
A degree zero element is thus of the form $a / s^n$, where $a \in \Gamma(X, F \otimes L^{\otimes n})$ . The restriction of $a$ is an element in $\Gamma(D(s),F \otimes L^{\otimes n})$.

At least in the latest version of the notes, the exercise statement contains a good bit of background information which should fill in some of your questions about what the left side means. Please add the full statement of the exercise in to your post with an [edit], and update the "I don't understand what the left side means..." paragraph if appropriate.

@KReiser I've made an edit.
